# Acumatica Enable Searchable Fields

Tags: c#, acumatica, erp

I'm trying to make a field that shows up in a selector searchable. Specifically, in the Kit Assembly screen it shows Inventory ID, but you can't search this field by default when picking your assembly in the selector. I had assumed it was a simple customization checkbox, but I'm not seeing the option to enable it. In the absolutest plainest of terms, how would you go about this?

I'm not very knowledgeable yet about where to place code snippets in a customization other than setting simple things like math calculations between fields, so please feel free to break this down Barney Style.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Log in with a user who has Customizer access rights.

Navigate to Kit Assembly screen. Select menu item Customization->Inspect Element and click on the field you need to customize. 
[image]

Then select Customize on the popup window:
[image]

You don't give enough information in your question to identify which field you need to customize, no field name or label contains 'assembly'.

For form fields you add the filter column names separated by comma in the GridProperties->FastFilterFields property:
[image]

For grid fields, you need to modify the RowTemplate element which is in the section labelled Levels in customization project editor. If there's no matching RowTemplate you'll need to add it from the Add Controls tab:

[image]

Comment: YES! Thank you. I am editing the Reference Nbr selector on the Assembly. I should have specified that. This is exactly what I was looking for.